# Sending several HTTP Requests in java - problem with OuputStreamWriter?

Tags: java, http, sockets

I am using Java in order to send HTTP Requests to webservices. I manage to send one, but I cannot send two. This is a part of my code (some parts removed for readability :

```
try {
String data =  "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap= ... datas xml ... </soap:Envelope>";
URL url = new URL(".......url........");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
conn.addRequestProperty("SOAPAction", .......action.......");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); // fail here for the second request

//write parameters
writer.write(data);
writer.flush();

// Get the response
StringBuffer answer = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {answer.append(line);
}
    writer.close();
reader.close();

//Output the response
String str=answer.toString();
// conn.disconnect(); // Should I put it ?
label.setText(str);
} 

catch (Exception ex) {label.setText(ex.getMessage());}
```

This request works fine. If I put the same after and do some tests, I find that it does not work (I change the names of variables, in case..). I have found that it fails at the line with the OuputStreamWriter. I get this error with getMessage in the exception :

> access denied (java.net.SocketPermission ....url..... connect,resolve)

How could I fix it ? I figure out it is possible to send several requests...
Is the method disconnect() useful here ?

I tried to send the request via an other class (in fact, I have a webpage and javascript call the requests one by one), and it does not work too..

Thank you very much for any advice or help !

===================== EDIT =======================

Here is a whole applet :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import netscape.javascript.JSException;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Test extends JApplet {
private JSObject jso;
private JLabel label = new JLabel();

public void init(){
    this.setSize(300, 80);

    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setForeground(Color.blue);
    label.setText("hello world");

    this.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public void doJavascript(){
    label.setText("hellooooooooo");
}


public void closeConnect(String SECTK, String SESSID){
    jso = JSObject.getWindow(this);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setForeground(Color.blue);
    try{
     String data ="dataaaaa";
     label.setText("yes2");
 URL url = new URL(".........url.............");
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
 conn.addRequestProperty("SOAPAction", ".....url........");
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 label.setText("yes25");
 OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
 label.setText("yes3");
 writer.write(data);
 writer.flush();

 StringBuffer answer = new StringBuffer();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
 String line;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(line);
 }
 writer.close();
 reader.close();
 //Output the response*/
    String str=answer.toString();
    conn.disconnect();
    label.setText(str);
 } 
 catch (Exception ex) {
// label.setText("nooo");
 label.setText(ex.getMessage());
}
this.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
}
```

If I call doJavascript from a javascript file, it works. If I call closeConnect from the same javascript file, it does not work, and I retrieve in my label "yes25", which is just before the "OuputStreamWriter"...

I hope it is clear.

Thanks for any help or advice

Comment: did you close and reopen the connection?

Comment: what do you mean ? by the disconnect() method ? I tried with and without it. I don't know how closing a connexion, except using that.. ?

Comment: Are you using applets or similar?

Comment: Yeah I am using a java applet, I forgot to mention it sorry

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using one of the multitude of Java libraries/APIs for communicating with Web Service endpoints? EG Spring-WS, AXIS, JAX-WS, etc?

Comment: You may be right, I didnt know them (I m a very beginner) but I thought juste Java was sufficient since one request works fine... I will look at these librairies. Thks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it : there is a security problem for calls from javascript to java for some kinds of methods - for example http requests : http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/#SECURITY_MODEL

So the code must bu changed like this :

```
final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

and

```
OutputStreamWriter writer;
                // This is needed as code called from Javascript does not have the rights to do this
                try
                {
                    writer = 
                        AccessController.doPrivileged(
                            new PrivilegedExceptionAction<OutputStreamWriter>() {
                                public OutputStreamWriter run() throws IOException {
                                    return new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
                catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
                    // e.getException() should be an instance of IOException,
                    // as only "checked" exceptions will be "wrapped" in a
                    // PrivilegedActionException.
                    throw (IOException) e.getException();
                }
```

and

```
StringBuffer answer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader reader;
                // This is needed as code called from Javascript does not have the rights to do this
                try
                {
                     reader = new BufferedReader(
                        AccessController.doPrivileged(
                            new PrivilegedExceptionAction<InputStreamReader>() {
                                public InputStreamReader run() throws IOException {
                                    return new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    );
                }
                catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
                    // e.getException() should be an instance of IOException,
                    // as only "checked" exceptions will be "wrapped" in a
                    // PrivilegedActionException.
                    throw (IOException) e.getException();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the second request going to a different server than where the applet was download from? If so, then that is the problem.

Applets cannot connect to or retrieve resources from any third party server (any server other than the server it originated from).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

I would recommend solving this problem by using RMI to have the applet communicate with the server, and have the server make the actual XML requests on the applet's behalf. This is really easy to do, and using the download server as a proxy like this enables applets to do all sorts of stuff that the security manager restricts them from doing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second request targets the same server than the first one. If I put the two requests in the init() of an applet (or two different applets), it works fine. But if I create a second class inside the applet of the first one, or inside another applet, it does not work, just as I described above. I don't think it is the problem you raise - but I will try to do everything in the init.

Comment: To precise, I think I could do everything in the init(), but it would reqlly help if I could use different classes for different requests, so I am still looking for.

Comment: It might help if you wrote a whole new applet just to reproduce this problem, and then post the entire source code here.

Comment: In fact it does not work if I include every request in the init(). I got the same error. I edit my first code by writing a whole applet.